# Blocking IP Address In Drupal 7 Via Code

Tags: rules

I want to know is there any function in DRUPAL 7 that I can send it an IP address as a parameter and it adds this ip to blacked_ips table ??

Indeed I have a rule that contains a Execution PHP action . In my action I want to add an IP to black list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't in core; [`system_block_ip_action()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_block_ip_action/7) is about as close it you'll get, but that blocks the current IP.

Such a function would be trivial to implement though:

```
function block_ip($ip) {
  if (!(bool)db_query("SELECT 1 FROM {blocked_ips} WHERE ip = :ip", array(':ip' => $ip))->fetchField()) {
    db_insert('blocked_ips')->fields(array('ip' => $ip))->execute();    
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Now my another question is if I want to use your mentioned function (block_ip) in my rules Execution php action, I need to define it at first. Please tell me where can I define this function ? in a sepecific PHP file or in execution php action ?

Comment: Custom code goes in a custom module @Mehrdad201, is that what you meant?

Comment: I mean I want to place this function in a php file and then call it from rules PHP execution action.
If I write it in a .module file, I must enable this module. right?

Answer (score 4):

You can use **[drupal_form_submit()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_form_submit/7)** to block the IP.

```
Case 1:

    function block_ip($ip) {
        $form_state['values'] = array();
        drupal_form_submit('system_ip_blocking_form', $form_state, $ip);
    }

Case 2:

    function block_ip($ip) {
        $form_state = array();
        $form_state['values']['ip'] = $ip;
        drupal_form_submit('system_ip_blocking_form', $form_state, $ip);
    }
```

Line $form_state['values']['ip'] = $ip; is optional as **system_ip_blocking_form** required IP as 3rd param. You can see function declaration at line 1392 in system.admin.inc

The advantage of using **drupal_form_submit()** is, it will handle all validation and set watchdog messages.